# How can I get the top N records of a MySQL table by excluding an array of groups?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, records

Here's a table example:

```
Table: websites

Domain            | Category | Popularity

google.com        | 0        | 13,430
yahoo.com         | 0        | 1,094
facebook.com      | 1        | 23,943
youtube.com       | 2        | 17,320
imdb.com          | 3        | 6,094
stackoverflow.com | 4        | 2,930
ebay.com          | 5        | 5,748
yandex.com        | 5        | 3,748
```

I'd like to return the top N results by excluding categories CE = [C1, C2, C3 ... Cn] ordered by popularity.

For example:

The TOP 3 results by excluding search engines CE = [0] ordered by popularity are:

```
Domain            | Category | Popularity

facebook.com      | 1        | 23,943
youtube.com       | 2        | 17,320
imdb.com          | 3        | 6,094
```

The TOP 3 results by excluding all categories except search engines CE = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] ordered by popularity are:

```
Domain            | Category | Popularity

google.com        | 0        | 13,430
yahoo.com         | 0        | 1,094
```

Let's work on the last query.

I expect it to look like this:

```
SELECT domain, category, popularity FROM (SELECT domain, category, popularity FROM websites WHERE category != [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] ORDER BY popularity) LIMIT 0, 3
```

1. How do I pass an array of excluded categories as a WHERE statement?
2. How do I order it by ascending / descending popularity order?
3. Do I order it before or after I select the ones with the right category type (performance wise)?

I don't care if the response is ordered or not by popularity. That's something I can *redo* client-side.

I know this is core-level stuff but is there any way of speeding it up? It is after all a whole table scan!

Comment: Why EXclude everything that is not, instead of INcluding everything that is?

Comment: Because, I like to punish myself. :) Also, it doesn't interrupt my train of thoughts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a `LIMIT` clause, all you have to do is make sure your `WHERE` clause filters out categories you don't want. Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE category NOT IN(category, list)
ORDER BY popularity DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

The way you'll pass in the list is by finding a way to build a comma separated list of the categories you want to filter out. For more information on the `IN` operator, see [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) link.

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/570eb/1) example that shows both your sample cases.

Answer (score 3):

```
select *
from websites
where Category in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
order by Popularity desc
limit 0,3;
```

will give you 3 most popular Domains that are in Category 1,2,3,4 or 5

```
select *
from websites
where Category not in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
order by Popularity desc
limit 0,3;
```

will give you 3 most popular Domains that are not in Category 1,2,3,4 or 5

Comment: It almost seems too easy, doesn't it?